# Why the Label in the ViewController is gone after I set the translucent to the background?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS swift. I try to change page from A to B ,and set the background of page-B to alpha 0.5 like the following code:

In **`A-ViewController`**:

```
    @IBAction func btnClick_aitrix_robot(_ sender: Any) {
            print("btnClick_aitrix_robot")


            let filterVC = QuestionViewController()
            filterVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.custom
            self.present(filterVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

In **`B-ViewController`:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
}
```

There has a **`Label`** in the **`page-B`** , but it disappear after I set the translucent to the background of page-B.

Did i missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add all the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guess you have created the `QuestionViewController` view in the interface builder. And that you have the `UILabel` that disappears set from there.

If thats the case, then the problem is the way you create the `QuestionViewController`. You need to tell it to load from the xib. You can do so by changing:

`let filterVC = QuestionViewController()`

for

`let filterVC = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuestionViewControllerIdentifier")`

Be aware that you need to set the identifier for the `QuestionViewController` ViewController from the Interface builder.

[image]